# Different geometrical concepts of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, vector-analysis

I'm a bit confused about the various geometric concepts of vectors.

I'm mainly trying to understand if we can classify any vector into one of two categories.The first category would be free vectors, that is an element  who is specified only by magnitude and direction, regardless of where it starts and ends ( regardless of the position ).
The second category would be bound vectors, that is, an element who is specified not only by magnitude and direction, but by where it starts and ends ( by its position ).

Should i be happy with this two categories when trying to understand and classify any kind of vector, or there is more to it ?

I went for a quick search in the wikipedia and found some kinds of vector :

Euclidean Vector, Displacement vector ( physics ), Position vector, Gradient Vector ( a vector that arises in vector calculus ) and "the vectors that define a Vector Field".

Would the position vector, gradient vector be examples of "free vectors" and would the Euclidean vector, Sisplacement vector and the vectors that define a Vector Field examples of "bound vectors" ?

Can i classify each kind of vector i mentioned in either bound or free vector categories ?    Can i mantain the geometrical concept of vector as being either bound or free in my mind? Am i missing anything ?

Comment: you're actually making an important distinction: if your 'bound vector' is to track both 'speed' and 'position' (i.e. in $\mathbb{R}^3$, 6 coordinates as opposed to only 3 for a 'free vector'), it's actually an element of a vector bundle (to every 'position' where the 'bound vector' can be attached there is associated a whole vector space, in which the vector takes its 'free vector' component). what makes it confusing is that in euclidean space, the vector space attached to any point can be identified with the space itself. example of 'bound vectors': look up tangent bundle

Comment: hmm speed or velocity ? Btw, considering a vector bundle wouldnt we have infinitely many vectors for each point ?

Comment: that's just the space in which the 'bound vectors' live..the $\mathbb R^3$-bundle on $\mathbb R^3$ is essentially the same as $\mathbb R^6$..also by speed i meant the whole vector not just its magnitude, maybe that's what you call velocity (but it could just as well be any other vector that applies to a certain position, such as acceleration etc)

Comment: by vector-bundle on R^3 do you mean, for example, that for the point (2,3,2) there is a vector space associated ( infintely many vectors) and for (2,3,2 + dz) there is another vector space associated ( infinitely many vectors ) ?

Comment: if by $dz$ you mean a scalar then yes..but i fear you're talking about an infinitesimal, which makes the statement quite meaningless as is. on general manifolds (such as a vector bundle), the differential is defined in more abstract terms than in multivariate analysis, and its componentwise expression is quite dependent on how the manifold is 'parametrized'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a tricky question, because there are a number of slightly different meanings of "vector" in mathematics, so the correct answer depends on which area you're working in.

However, at the level of sophistication where we're talking about "magnitude and direction" as a possible definition of vectors, the answer is unambiguously that **a vector is *always* what you call a "free" vector**. It is important for the application of vectors to geometry that the vector from $(0,0)$ to $(1,2)$ is *the same vector* as the one that takes from $(42,1000)$ to $(43,1002)$. Of course you sometimes need to wrap up the combination of a starting point and a vector into a single mathematical object, and it's fine to do so -- just don't call the combined object a "vector", because that will confuse people. It's just a pair of a point and a vector (or, equivalently in Euclidean space, an ordered pair of a starting point and an endpoint).

In linear algebra we meet the concept of an **abstract vector space**, which is generalized to contexts where "magnitude and direction" make little sense. In this abstract sense a vector is any member of something that satisfies the vector space axioms. Note that the set of what you call "bound" vectors *doesn't* satisfy these axioms (with any reasonable definition of what vector addition and scalar multiplication should mean), so they are not even abstract vectors.

By the way, since your examples sound a bit like you might be coming at this from a physics viewpoint, note that physicists usually *don't* call the elements of arbitrary abstract vector spaces "vectors" at all. They have other uses for the word.

What about **vector fields**, you ask? A vector field is not *one* vector -- it is a function that assigns some vector to each point of some space. However, the vectors that are values of a vector field are ordinary ("free") vectors -- in particular they don't know at which point of the vector field we got them out of. This is important too, because in many applications we're interested in whether the vector field has the same (or approximately the same) values at two different points, and we wouldn't be able to speak of that if the identity of one of the vector field's values depended intrinsically on which point it was a value *at*.

(An aside: It is not uncommon in physics jargon to speak of a vector *field* as simply "a vector", especially when speaking about equations that are supposed to hold at every point in the space. Strictly speaking that's an abuse of terminology, but it seems to work well for them. It doesn't seem to have anything to do with the incidental fact that the set of all possible vector fields constitute an abstract vector space in the mathematical sense).

Unfortunately, there's an exception to the above, namely when the vector field doesn't live in the usual Euclidean space but in a more general **manifold**, such as a curved surface in space. In that case each point on the surface has its own private space of **tangent vectors**, and a vector field then selects for each point a particular vector in its private tangent space. Then the vectors do know which point's tangent space they belong to, and we have to take special measures if we want to compare the value of the vector field at two different points (for example, to differentiate it).

As a simple example of this, consider the surface of the earth, and a velocity field on it. The velocity vectors need to stay within the surface, so at a flat piece of ground the velocity can be north, sough, east, and west or some combination of them -- but not up an down. However, on the side of a steep hill, "due north" might not be available as a direction at all, because that points into the ground, and similarly "south" points into free air. So each point on the surface has its own space of possible tangent vectors.

Note, however that the tangent vectors of a manifold don't behave quite like you describe "bound" vectors. In your description, a "bound" vector is supposed to have a start point and an end point, but a tangent vector is tied to *one* point on the surface, with no distinction between a start point and an end point. Again, a velocity vector is a good example -- if a particle is currently at a particular point and moving due north at $10^{-9}$ times the speed of light, it makes little sense to attach a separate endpoint to its velocity vector.

Confused yet?

Comment: Really good answear, just one question ... I was reading the definition of "Euclidean Vector" in wikipedia and it first says "In mathematics, physics, and engineering, a Euclidean vector (sometimes called a geometric[1] or spatial vector,[2] or—as here—simply a vector) is a geometric object that has magnitude (or length) and direction and can be added to other vectors according to vector algebra" which clearly specifies an object who has only magnitude and direction, whose position clearly doesn`t matter.

Comment: Then it goes on and says  "A Euclidean vector is frequently represented by a line segment with a definite direction, or graphically as an arrow, connecting an initial point A with a terminal point B,[3] and denoted". This clearly mentions that the same object`s position matters, since it must be used to connect an initial point with a terminal point. So should we consider the Euclidean vector a "free vector" or a "bound vector" ?

Comment: @nerdy: You need to distinguish between what the vector _is_ and how it is _represented_. The representation as an arrow has a lot of attributes that are _not_ part of which vector the representation represents -- such as the thickness of the line, the size of the arrowhead, and where in the plane we draw it. Just as switching from a two-short-lines-at-an-angle arrowhead to a filled-in-triangle one doesn't make the vector a different one, drawing it at another place doesn't change which vector it is either. Or: just because the representation _has_ a position doesn't mean it _matters_.